# Google Script - findText is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm trying to make a script for my Google document so I can format specific paragraphs in some "chat log" segments according to the nickname the paragraph begins with (example: "myNickname: blah blah blah").

I made a test function to test out findText() but when I execute `test()`, it returns this error: `ReferenceError: findText is not defined   test @ Code.gs:21`

Here is the complete script:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  DocumentApp.getUi()
  .createMenu("FORMATTING")
    .addItem("Test", "test")

  .addToUi();
}

function formatNickname(nickname, style) {
  nickname = nickname + ":"; // Dialogue is in a 'chat log' format, so it's displayed as "NICKNAME: Blah blah blah"

  let foundText = findText(nickname); 

  foundText.getText().setTextStyle(style);

  console.log(foundText); // Debug
}

function test() {
  formatNickname("BAB", findText("AA:").getText.getTextStyle()); // The second parameter is for debug reasons. AA is a character with a specific text style.
}
```

And here is my appsscript.json:

```
{
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents"
  ],
  "timeZone": "America/Sao_Paulo",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

I have Google Apps Script API turned on in my user settings, as instructed in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63516294/19762737)

Comment: Where is the definition of `findText` method?

Comment: @AngYC findText is already part of the API. [Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#findText(String))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`findText`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#findText(String)) is not a global function, you can only call it when you have a `Text` element selected. You have to first obtain the current `Document` using [`getActiveDocument()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#getactivedocument) (or other ways as long as you have access), then perform your search from that document.

In addition, [`getTextStyle()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#gettextstyle) and [`setTextStyle()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#settextstylestyle) only exists in Sheets but not Docs, you have to use [`getAttributes()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#getattributes) and [`setAttributes()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setattributesattributes) for that instead. I have personally try to setup and run myself and here's a working code example to copy the style of one text element to another:

```js
function onOpen(e) {
  DocumentApp.getUi()
    .createMenu("FORMATTING")
    .addItem("Test", "test")
    .addToUi();
}

function formatNickname(text, nickname, attributes) {
  nickname = nickname + ":"; // Dialogue is in a 'chat log' format, so it's displayed as "NICKNAME: Blah blah blah"
  const foundText = text.findText(nickname).getElement().asText();
  foundText.setAttributes(attributes);
}

function test() {
  const body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  const text = body.editAsText();
  formatNickname(text, "BAB", text.findText('AA:').getElement().asText().getAttributes()); // The second parameter is for debug reasons. AA is a character with a specific text style.
}
```